# Configuring PhoneGap 3.5 in Xcode 5.1 breaks plugins

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

So I have an interesting issue. I can create an iOS application using:

```
cordova platform add ios
cordova plugin add PluginSrc/MyPlugin
```

Everything works 100%, I can click the button in the WebView and the plugin runs.

I then add some framework files to the plugin, however the frameworks throw an error message because I did not set the linker flags. So I open XCode and add the following to the "other linker flags" settings under build settings:

```
-mthumb -lstdc++ -lz -lm -mfpu=neon
```

On build, everything works however when I click the button I get the following error message:

```
CDVPlugin class MyPlugin (pluginName: MyPlugin) does not exist.
ERROR: Plugin 'MyPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
```

Any reason for this? Is there a way to fix this? Seems like xcode messes up the project file.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update. I committed working changes to GIT. I then edited the settings via Xcode and compared the borked project.pbxproj file with the one in GIT

I found that Xcode rearranged a lot of settings and completely left others out. Mainly settings around the plugin that was installed.

So to fix my issue and get the flags into the project file without breaking Phonegap I had manually added the flags to the project.pbxproj using sublime.

My Project builds perfectly now with no issues.

If anyone has come across a better way of doing this please let me know.